# A page-turning interface for iOS apps in Leaves Github Project xCode

Tags: xcode, github, page-curl

I'm trying to implement leaves project link is below:

https://github.com/brow/leaves

but there are serverl errors I couldn't find out the issues that why there are so many errors

So would anyone please help me how can i solve this problem

I don't know where I'm doing mistake, I download the zip file and then extract it and run the project that's it.

I'm attaching the screenshot of the errors as well.

[image]

You can see the errors in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import QuarzCore and CoreGraphics frameworks to your project.

Add this your .h file of the class that causes the errors:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: M, is there anything in the project that i can zoom in and zoom out the pdf document with page curl effect ???

Comment: M ? can you please tell me further ?

Comment: You can search the web for open source solutions that support zooming or implement the functionality on your own.